# Как подключиться к wifi на ubuntu если нет iwlist?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, wifi

Установил на ноутбук ubuntu 18.04 доступен только терминал без графической оболочки. Нужно подключить ноут к моей домашней сети wifi подскажите как этот сделать? команда `iw dev` сетевую карту вроде нашла, а вот `iwlist scan` для нее не выполняет пишет command not found , что странно.

Comment: `/sbin/iwlist`.

Comment: Есть куча других пакетов для подключения к вифи же

Comment: _iw_ умеет, но для WPA нужно что-то типа *wpa_supplicant*.